# How to customize a scatter matrix to see all titles?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm running this code to build a scatter matrix. The problem is that the plot looks like a mess, because it's impossible to see the names of variables (see image below). Is there any way to change the orientation of titles and switch off the ticks with numbers?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

train = pd.read_csv('data/train.csv', parse_dates=[0])

plt.figure()
a = pd.scatter_matrix(train, alpha=0.05, figsize=(10,10), diagonal='hist')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As a minimal `scatter_matrix` example to switch off axis ticks and rotate the labels,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
try:
    from pandas.tools.plotting import scatter_matrix
except ImportError:
    #Fix suggested by @Raimundo Jimenez as tools is deprecated
    from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 4), columns=['long label', 'testing', 'another label', 'something else'])

sm = scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.2, figsize=(6, 6), diagonal='kde')

#Change label rotation
[s.xaxis.label.set_rotation(45) for s in sm.reshape(-1)]
[s.yaxis.label.set_rotation(0) for s in sm.reshape(-1)]

#May need to offset label when rotating to prevent overlap of figure
[s.get_yaxis().set_label_coords(-0.3,0.5) for s in sm.reshape(-1)]

#Hide all ticks
[s.set_xticks(()) for s in sm.reshape(-1)]
[s.set_yticks(()) for s in sm.reshape(-1)]

plt.show()
```

and similarly, you can adjust labels, resize, etc with any of the axis objects contained in the returned handle from `scatter_matrix`. This results in,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`pandas.tools.plotting.scatter_matrix` is now deprecated. Use `pandas.plotting.scatter_matrix` instead.

Updated code from the one proposed by Ed Smith (@ed-smith):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 4), columns=['long label', 'testing', 'another label', 'something else'])

sm = pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.2, figsize=(6, 6), diagonal='kde')

#Change label rotation
[s.xaxis.label.set_rotation(45) for s in sm.reshape(-1)]
[s.yaxis.label.set_rotation(0) for s in sm.reshape(-1)]

#May need to offset label when rotating to prevent overlap of figure
[s.get_yaxis().set_label_coords(-0.3,0.5) for s in sm.reshape(-1)]

#Hide all ticks
[s.set_xticks(()) for s in sm.reshape(-1)]
[s.set_yticks(()) for s in sm.reshape(-1)]

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Do you know a way to round the ticks instead of hiding them? Sometimes I get ticks with 10 digits which is pretty ugly