# How to put a title on each scatter_matrix in jupyter + pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter

So, I have multiple samplings of a data-set taken at different times.
For each sampling I want to plot a scatter matrix, and each scatter matrix should have the time of the sampling as title.

The problem is there is no argument "title" for `pandas.tools.plotting.scatter_matrix`

When I try to print() the title before plotting the graph, it will print all the titles before plotting the graphs.

```
for qid in qids:
    date = db[collection].find_one({ "querySummary.qid": qid }, {"querySummary.date":1})["querySummary"]["date"].isoformat()
    print(date) # does not provide the desired result
    cursor = db[collection].find({ "querySummary.qid": qid })
    cols = ["resultNum", "col2", "col3", "col4"] # list of columns labels
    rows = [] # will be populated below
    for result in cursor:
        rows.append([result["resultNum"], result["col2"], result["col3"], result["col4"]])
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols);
    scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.3, figsize=(16,16), diagonal='kde', marker=date)
```

By running the code, the titles are all printed before the first scatter_matrix is finally plotted:

[image: Result not as expected]

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize a scatter matrix to see all titles?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32560932/how-to-customize-a-scatter-matrix-to-see-all-titles)

Comment: @su79eu7k Not a duplicate, different questions, he is asking about labels (erroneously calling them titles)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not use `print(date)` in that case. Instead, please try `plt.suptitle(date)` for each `scatter_matrix` like below.

```
for qid in qids:
    date = db[collection].find_one({ "querySummary.qid": qid }, {"querySummary.date":1})["querySummary"]["date"].isoformat()
    cursor = db[collection].find({ "querySummary.qid": qid })
    cols = ["resultNum", "col2", "col3", "col4"] # list of columns labels
    rows = [] # will be populated below

    for result in cursor:
        rows.append([result["resultNum"], result["col2"], result["col3"], result["col4"]])
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols);
    scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.3, figsize=(16,16), diagonal='kde', marker='o')

    plt.suptitle(date)
```

Answer (score 1):

For your case, I think the best way to proceed would be to plot directly with matplotlib rather than using the plots from pandas. Refer this: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#plotting-directly-with-matplotlib

You might need to try something like

```
dummy = scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.3, figsize=(16,16), diagonal='kde', marker=date)
plt.figure()
plt.title(date)
plt.plot(dummy)
plt.show()
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me, i get "TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'AxesSubplot'"

Comment: Can you try 
`plt.hold(True)

scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.3, figsize=(16,16), diagonal='kde', marker=date)

plt.title(date)

plt.show()`

Comment: @NitinKashyap I tried it, but it creates prints an additional empty plot before each scatter matrix and the titles appears inside a cell of the matrix. If i set the title before the scatter_plot the title appears on top of the additional empty plot.